# Duplicating row dynamically in h:dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable

I have a data table

```
<h:dataTable value="#{vendor.vh.currentVendorVO.vfms}" var="row">
```

In `VendorVO`

```
private VFM[] vfms;
public VFM[] getVfms() {
    return vfms;
}
public void setVfms(VFM[] vfms) {
    this.vfms = vfms;
}
```

In `VFM`

```
private String orderTypeId;
private String fulfillTypeId;
private int orderSeq;
private String lastUpdated;
private String lastUpdatedBy;
private boolean lastItem;
private String action = "none";
```

I would like to duplicate the `<h:dataTable>` row when a button is clicked.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dynamically expansible `ArrayList` instead of a fixed size array `[]`.

```
private List<VFM> vfms; // +getter (setter is unnecessary)
```

Then, it's just a matter of letting the button invoke `add()` method on it with new `VFM` instance.

```
<h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{bean.addVfm}" />
```

```
public void addVfm() {
    vfms.add(new VFM());
}
```

If you intend to have this button on every row which copies a new `VFM` instance, then just pass it along and add a copy constructor.

```
<h:commandButton value="Copy" action="#{bean.copyVfm(row)}" />
```

```
public void copyVfm(VFM vfm) {
    vfms.add(new VFM(vfm));
}
```

```
public VFM(VFM vfm) {
    orderTypeId = vfm.orderTypeId;
    fulfillTypeId = vfm.fulfillTypeId;
    orderSeq = vfm.orderSeq;
    lastUpdated = vfm.lastUpdated;
    lastUpdatedBy = vfm.lastUpdatedBy;
    lastItem = vfm.lastItem; 
    action = vfm.action;
}
```